# Variable null pointer exception

Tags: java, android

I have main class (extends Application)which stores static main variable (the calculator of the app). So after pausing the app (home button or calling)

```
06-21 00:43:14.916: E/AndroidRuntime(26676): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-21 00:43:14.916: E/AndroidRuntime(26676): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-21 00:43:14.916: E/AndroidRuntime(26676):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-21 00:43:14.916: E/AndroidRuntime(26676):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-21 00:43:14.916: E/AndroidRuntime(26676):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-21 00:43:14.916: E/AndroidRuntime(26676):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-21 00:43:14.916: E/AndroidRuntime(26676):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-21 00:43:14.916: E/AndroidRuntime(26676):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-21 00:43:14.916: E/AndroidRuntime(26676):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-21 00:43:14.916: E/AndroidRuntime(26676):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-21 00:43:14.916: E/AndroidRuntime(26676):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-21 00:43:14.916: E/AndroidRuntime(26676): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 00:43:14.916: E/AndroidRuntime(26676):    at com.AMain$CalcTask.doInBackground(AMain.java:106)
06-21 00:43:14.916: E/AndroidRuntime(26676):    at ru.ps.horoscope.AMain$CalcTask.doInBackground(AMain.java:1)
06-21 00:43:14.916: E/AndroidRuntime(26676):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-21 00:43:14.916: E/AndroidRuntime(26676):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-21 00:43:14.916: E/AndroidRuntime(26676):    ... 5 more
```

the 106 string: `if (!_.calc.Calculated) CALCULATE_();`

```
_ extends Application
```

HOW TO FIX IT?

```
       @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (!_.calc.Calculated) CALCULATE_();
                return null;
            }
```

Comment: You have to provide more code. But to answer, there's something that you don't initialize (and obviously setted to null)

Comment: Can you please post the code in your doInBackground()?

Comment: _.calc was defined and got lots of calculations. No onresume, onstart, onpause, onstop. just pressing home and back. Sometime all works correct. But after calling the application drops off.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on line 106, then debug your application. When you get to the breakpoint, what is null? Did you initialize it?

Comment: yes. it was initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_` or `calc` is null. You would need to post code to get more info than this.

Comment: public class _ extends Application { etc...  and static _Calc calc; they defined before andd got lots of calclations

Comment: Have you specified `_` as your application in your manifest? E.g. `<application android:name="com.your.package.name._">`? Havr you initialized `_Calc`?

Comment: <application android:name="com.your.package.name._" - is it importaint? may be this is the error. i didnt add it.

Comment: Yes, you need to tell Android that you want `_` to be your Application class. This is done by editing `AndroidManifest.xml`. Find your `<application>` tag and put in the path to where `_` is stored.

Comment: thanks. I will try it. If this is the error i will write it later after i check it.

Comment: You was right. I forgot about importance of this feature.